# Cant get Django debug-toolbar 1.9 to work on django 2.0

Tags: django

I have installed Django debug-toolbar using pip, and added 'debug_toolbar' to the installation app list.

When i run server the toolbar isn't displayed. what step am i missing ?!

Comment: The automatic setup has been removed. There are several other steps in the [installation instructions](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html).

Comment: no i haven't, but I've seen many links that explains how to install it with the same steps i have done but with older django  version . that is why i assumed that its related to my django version

Comment: Can you include the settings you’ve put in so far and include info about your environment? Are you using Vagrant, for example?

Comment: I have started a new django project, and just added 'debug_toolbar' to the INSTALLED_APPS and ''debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware'' to MIDDLEWARE nothing else, and i am using virtual environment wrapper

Comment: Then you’ve missed out the url conf step from the instructions.

Comment: yes thank you that did fix it

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in `2.0.7` sort of following [installation guide](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) was:

#### 1) Install new *django* and *debug toolbar*

```
pip install -U django
pip install django-debug-toolbar
```

#### 2) *Migrate* `settings.py` from `1.x` to `2.x`:

I created dummy project: `django-admin startproject mysite` and checked out default `mysite\mysite\settings.py` for `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE`. All that was left was adding `debug_toolbar`:

```py
# As mentioned in the last step of Installation Guide
INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1', '::1']

# Default config + some changes
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',     # Add this
    'mysite',            # Your app
]

# Default config + some changes
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', # Add this
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

#### 3) Add URLs

Once again, just follow the [Installation Guide](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#urlconf) and add this to URLs config:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

Comment: Thanks for this, It would be great to add this to official debug-toolbar docs, maybe I wasnt looking at the docs for most recent version